# Extract Data from Huge file using TikaOnDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx, apache-tika, chunks

Is there a way in **TikaOnDotNet library** to extract data from huge file without compromising performance? 
It took around 2-3 minutes to extract data from 52MB XLSX file on a high end machine.

I have a scenario where I need to extract data from different file types.
For .txt file, if the file size is greater than 10MB I'm dividing it into chunks of 10MB using File Stream and dividing by length but same will not work for XLSX, PDF, etc.

My question is, does TikaOnDotNet library has the ability to handle this itself or we only need to split XLSX files in chunks using Interop or OpenXMLSDK and pass it to TikaOnDotNet library?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Sample File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMZ_jnRpaiaNyuY8ecmnwUV9nbB5mX8V/view?usp=sharing

**Sample Code:**

```
using TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction;
public static string extractDatafromTikaOnDotNet(string filepath)
{
     try
     {
          TextExtractor textExtractor = new TextExtractor();
          string result = textExtractor.Extract(filepath).Text;
          return result;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Even better if you could provide the huge file as a link that we could download and reproduce.

Comment: @mjwills - I have added the code to extract and reg file, you can create any xlsx file and make it huge by coy pasting the data in it :).
My file is confidential, if you still need a big file let me know :)

Comment: You don't need Tika to read `xlsx` files, especially on .NET. 52MB isn't that big either. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. You can read them directly, eg using a GZipStream and XmlReader,  or use the Open XML SDK to read them. [How to: Parse and read a large spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet) shows how to read the SAX-like OpenXmlReader to read *really* large files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - We are using Tika as we need to read files of different formats.

Comment: @mjwills - i have attached a google drive link for sample file